# Get dates with in consecutive 50 days of given date

Tags: t-sql

Activity table:

```
create table #activity(id int, begin_date datetime, end_date datetime)
insert into #activity values(1, '1/1/2017', '1/31/2017')

insert into #activity values(1, '9/1/2017', '9/15/2017')

insert into #activity values(1, '4/1/2017', '4/15/2017')

insert into #activity values(1, '2/5/2017', '2/15/2017')

insert into #activity values(1, '8/1/2017', '8/31/2017')

Insert into #activity values(2, '11/1/2016', '11/15/2016')
```

Now input date is 12/1/2016 and id, would like to get all activities within 50 days after 12/1/2016. Query should return activities with begin dates 1/1/2017, 2/5/2017 (because this is within 50 days of 1/31/2017), and 4/1/17.

8/1/2017 and 9/1/2017 of id 1 shouldn't be selected 8/1 is not with  in 50 days of 4/15 and 50 day cycle was broken.

TIA

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: It's great you posted sample data as DDL+DML. However, your question still needs expected results and your current attempt to get it. Please [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: Expected output is:should return activities with begin dates 1/1/2017, 2/5/2017 (because this is within 50 days of 1/31/2017), and 4/1/17.

Answer (score 0):

The OP says:

> would like to get all activities within 50 days after 12/1/2016

one possible query to achieve that result would be

```
-- get all activities with a begin_date within 50 days of input_date
select *
from #activity as a
where @input_date <= a.begin_date and a.begin_date < dateadd(day, 50, @input_date)
```

However, the OP then says:

> Query should return activities with begin dates 1/1/2017, 2/5/2017 (because this is within 50 days of 1/31/2017), and 4/1/17. 8/1/2017 and 9/1/2017 of id 1 shouldn't be selected 8/1 is not with in 50 days of 4/15 and 50 day cycle was broken.

This would indicate that you  want to find all sequential activities starting after 12/1/2016 where the gap between sequential activities is less than 50 days.

One possible approach for this is to use the [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. An example of how to use the lag function on this problem is:

```
select
    a.*
    , lag(a.end_date, 1, @input_date) over (order by a.end_date) as previous_end
    , datediff(day, lag(a.end_date, 1, @input_date)  over (order by a.end_date), a.begin_date) as previous_end_to_this_begin
from #activity as a
where @input_date <= a.begin_date
order by a.begin_date
```

Simplifying that slightly would produce this:

```
-- get all activities in a row where the gap between activities is less than 50
select * from #activity as a where @input_date <= a.begin_date and a.begin_date < (
select
    min(a.begin_date) as first_begin_to_not_include
from
    (
        select
            a.begin_date
            , datediff(day, lag(a.end_date, 1, @input_date)  over (order by a.end_date), a.begin_date) as previous_end_to_this_begin
        from #activity as a
        where @input_date <= a.begin_date
    ) as a
where a.previous_end_to_this_begin > 50
)
order by a.begin_date
```